index.html not found spring MVC Rest Angular Deploy in War to Tomcat
Links i've tried:

Integration of Angular 5 with Spring MVC
404 Page while running Spring and angular in same port
No mapping for GET / in SpringMVC
https://www.programming-free.com/2014/01/spring-mvc-40-restful-web-services.html
Mixing Spring MVC with Angular.JS
Run Spring4MVC with Angular 2 on a single server

Problem: Currently have old spring mvc (NOT Spring Boot) backend, jsp pages, apache tiles.  Tiles has been EOL'ed, and we have to upgrade to Jakarta EE. Latest spring framework dropped support for tiles. We decided to go with angular frontend and change controllers to @RestControllers that return jsons in ResponseEntity objects.
App build/deploys with no errors, and i am able to hit sample Controller endpoints.
homeController.java and get expected response in browser and with curls.
@RestController
public class HomeController extends YController {
@GetMapping(value = "/content", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity home(HttpServletRequest request){
        //do home stuff
        return  new ResponseEntity("/home.html", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}

web.xml
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="idvalue0" metadata-complete="true" version="2.5">

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
      org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/index.html</location>
  </error-page>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>

index.html has <base href="/">
File Structure:

mvcApp

module1
module2
webModule

src

main

java

controllers

HomeController.java




resources
webApp

WEB-INF

web.xml
rest-servlet.xml


index.html
...other files from angular dist folder after ng build











the rest-servlet.xml has all imports for other context files as well as <mvc:annotation-driven/> tag and authorizationContext bean.
I've read that for this type of setup to work, all traffic should be redirected to index.html so angular can take care of all frontend work. But when i deploy war file to tomcat, i get 404 when i localhost:8080/webApp/index.html, even with 404 redirected to index.html in web.xml.
Anyone have an idea of what I am missing?
